# How do I docuSign multiple documents in an envelope once using docuSign Rest API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating composite templates that work correctly and I'm running into this issue.

I am adding 2 templates to sign via docusign. I set the routing orders for both of them as shown below:

```
 Form 1  
    Order 1   RoleName signer       test1@gmail.com
    Order 2   RoleName signer2      test2@gmail.com
 Form 2
    Order 1   RoleName dataEntry    test1@gmail.com
    Order 2   RoleName dataEntry2   test2@gmail.com
```

This will send one email to test@gmail.com. This user completes all of his fields for both Form 1 and Form 2 in one request. This is what I want and expect. However, when test1@gmail.com completes their process, test2@gmail.com will receive 2 different emails. One to sign form 1 and the other to sign form 2. I'm trying to understand why test2@gmail.com doesn't work the same as test1@gmail.com. **Can someone help explain what the reason is for receiving 2 separate emails for test2@gmail.com may be and if there's a way to fix it?**

Note: When I do this via the docuSign website, it doesn't allow for the same recipient to be in that same routingOrder. It will bring up the error:

```
  The role 'signer' conflicts with 'dataEntry'
  The role 'signer2' conflicts with 'dataEntry2'
```

This behavior seemed strange to me since I'm able to send the envelope using the docusign rest API. **If somebody could give me some clarification on this as well I'd appreciate it**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unable to repro the issue you describe.  Here's what I did, and the Result:

- I created two separate templates in DocuSign, each having a single document and two recipients/signers (with Role Names and Routing Orders that you specify above in your question).
- I used the REST API (JSON request included below) to create/send an Envelope from these two Templates, specifying identical recipient information (name/email/recipient ID/routing order) for Recipient 1 and Recipient 2 across both *Inline Template* structures.
- Result:  Recipient 1 receives an email first, opens the envelope, and signs both documents at once.  Then Recipient 2 receives an email, opens the envelope, and signs both documents at once.  The Envelope status is "Completed" at that point.

I've included my API request below for your reference -- perhaps compare/contrast this with what you're doing?  Also -- make sure that Recipient information (Name / Email / Recipient ID /  Routing Order) is ***identical*** (including ***case***) for each recipient between the first *Inline Template* and the second *Inline template* within the API Request -- any small difference in Name/Email/Recipient Id/Routing Order, and DocuSign will treat them as different/separate people (recipients).

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign",
  "emailBlurb": "Please sign...thanks!",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
  {
    "serverTemplates": [
    {
        "sequence" : 1,
        "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID_1"
    }],
    "inlineTemplates": [
    {
        "sequence" : 2,
        "recipients": {
            "signers" : [{
                "email": "adamsemail@outlook.com",
                "name": "Adam Adamson",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "signer",
                "routingOrder": "1"
              },
              {
                "email": "bobsemail@outlook.com",
                "name": "Bob Burns",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "signer2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
              }
            ]
        }
    }]
  },
  {
    "serverTemplates": [
    {
        "sequence" : 1,
        "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID_2"
    }],
    "inlineTemplates": [
    {
        "sequence" : 2,
        "recipients": {
            "signers" : [{
                "email": "adamsemail@outlook.com",
                "name": "Adam Adamson",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "dataEntry",
                "routingOrder": "1"
              },
              {
                "email": "bobsemail@outlook.com",
                "name": "Bob Burns",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "dataEntry2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
              }
            ]
        }
    }]
  }]  
}
```

Comment: That was my issue. I wasn't using the same names and recipientIds. Thank you again, you've been a great help.